# Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}'

Tags: ios, singleton

I add my sound manager (it is singleton to play sounds in my game) and have this issue:

Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:  name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}'

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) VSSoundSystem *soundSystem;
```

in - (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size of my scene:

```
self.soundSystem = [VSSoundSystem sharedSystem];
[self addChild:self.soundSystem];
```

I need to add it as a child because I need run actions

VSSoundManager init:

```
+ (id)sharedSystem {
static VSSoundSystem *sharedSystem = nil;
@synchronized(self) {
    if (sharedSystem == nil)
        sharedSystem = [[self alloc] init];
}

return sharedSystem;
```

}

it works fine but crashes on second level loading

Answer (score 2):

What framework you are using? cocos2d?
My guess is that, when you load the second level you add the singleton AGAIN to another scene.
Since it is a singleton, it will probably still have the old, destroyed scene as parent.

You can try something like this:

```
[self.soundSystem removeFromParent]
```

or

```
[self.soundSystem removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO]
```

just before you destroy your old scene.

Comment: Thanks! It works I added `[self.soundSystem removeFromParent];` just before `[self addChild:self.soundSystem];`. PS I'm using SpriteKit

Comment: Great! So you can accept the answer (by clicking the little check mark on the left of it) so other people know this is the working solution!